# Access DAO Performance issue

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, dao

I'm using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DBEngine` to write data into an existing `accdb` template. This is done by certain class in a certain assembly.

Now I'm observing two cases: When I start my routine (debug build) within a xunit (1.9.2 with VS runner 2.0.1) test as a 32bit process within TE.ProcessHost.Managed.exe it needs about a minute to complete. Starting it as release build from a console application in 32 bit mode it needs more than 12 minutes.
I'm just instantiating a `new DbEngine()` and later call `OpenTable(name)` per table to fill and table.Update() per row to insert (no updates, inserts only). The assembly references `Microsoft.Office.interop.access.dao.dll` version 15.0.4420.1017 (Access 2010).

I'm looking for a clue where to start digging for the reason for these massive discrepancy.

**EDIT:**
Basically, it's a copy job from SQL-Server to an access db, thus it first reads the data via ADO from SQL-Server and than inserts this into the accdb. Like this (not the exact code):

```
foreach(var tableName in tables)
{
  readSqlIntoArray(tablename, tableData);
  var daoTable = daoDb.OpenTable(tableName);
  foreach(var row in tableData)
  {
    // ... add new record and copy data

    daoTable.Update();  // this is the expensive call in console app
  }
}
```

The unit test just creates the parameters for the copy job, creates the relevant object and starts the job. The console app does right the same. Profiling, timing and debugging always lead to `table.Update()` being the call with most cost. The SQL read shows no differences and ist therefor ruled out as cause of the problem.

The reason for asking here was actually, that I need an idea, where I can further investigate, since the code itself shows no obvious differences.

There is no reflection, generics, unsafe code or hidden artifacts in the calling methods (runner vs console app), that could explain such behavior, since both of them only build the runtime parameters and call the job. I even compared these parameters by char.
So I wondered, if there is some 'environmental difference' between console app and VS test runner, since I'm dealing with a COM object here.

**UPDATE 2:**

I had some time to investigate this issue again, these days.
So I added timing measurements to compare the individual steps. Fetching data from SQL Server is done in similiar time. The interesting part is again here:

```
foreach(var tableName in tables)
{
  readSqlIntoArray(tablename, tableData);
  var daoTable = daoDb.OpenTable(tableName);

  foreach(var row in tableData)
  {
    var rowArray = row.ItemArray;

    // because of type conversions this loop is necessary
    for (int i = 0; i < rowArray.Length; i++)
    {
        var srcValue = rowArray[i];
        if (srcValue.GetType() == typeof(TimeSpan))
        {
            // TimeSpan cannot be automatically converted and would cause exception
            tabl.Fields[i].Value = ((TimeSpan)srcValue).ToString(@"hh\:mm");
        }
        else if (srcValue.GetType() == typeof(Guid))
        {
            // Guid cannot be automatically converted and would cause exception
            // so wrap it as string
            tabl.Fields[i].Value = ((Guid)srcValue).ToString();
         }
         else
         {
             // even this assignment is taking longer in console app
             // than in testrunner (te.processhost.managed.exe)
             tabl.Fields[i].Value = srcValue;
         }
    }

    daoTable.Update();  
  }
}
```

It seems, that the assignments of the fields of a table row seem to behave differently, although it's exactly the same code lines. In debugger I cannot see, if the underlying COM objects are always of the same type in test and console.
Anyone with such experiences in COM objects within managed apps?

Comment: How many rows?  Is the MSAccess db file stored locally or on a network?  or does it use SQL Server for storage?

Comment: It is a local access db on hard disk, about 20 tables with very varying row counts, largest ones up to 60k

Comment: Gather facts first, use a profiler.

Comment: I wasn't aware of profilers being able to work on xunit tests.

Comment: Are you using reflection within your stuff?  Have you tried using the console app to run the debug build (minus the xunit stuff)?  Consider what else is different between your console app and your xunit.  It sounds like your console app might be some kind of runner that calls a lib and your xunit is calling just the lib.  It is hard to tell what is different from your description (above).

Comment: @tgolisch: Sorry, what do you mean by '...some kind of runner that calls a lib and your xunit is calling just the lib.' What would be the difference?

Comment: When I write a lib, I usually make a test jig (runner).  It loads the lib and calls each fcn.  It helps me test or isolate any problems.  Sometimes, my runner (test jig) is faster than the prod app that loads/runs the lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While analyzing the problem and asking about COM-objetcs I found out the simple and defintite reason: The apartment state of the application. If it is not set to STA, COM objects need complex marshalling and will pack improper calls into proxies, which is very expensive.

Decorating the console application with `[STAThread]` was the only thing necessary. I guess, the visual studio test runner is automatically started single threaded while normal applications are not, by default. 
COM and its affinity to STA was the key I was looking for the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

One approach may be to utilize passthru queries in MSAccess file to retrieve data from SQLServer, and using an insert query copy the data into the local access table(s).  Since there is no user code it would be curious to see if there is a performance difference.  If not, then it is likely an external problem, like disk IO, indexing, or network problems (assuming SQL Server is on a different computer).